# Does SP 2013 Preview support or show msg files

Tags: email

I know SharePoint 2013 has file preview capabilities. What are the file types supported?

Answer (score 2):

there are two thing,
One is Master page preview and 2nd thing Preview the Files in browser which is supported with Office Web Apps.

When used with SharePoint Server 2013, Office Web Apps Server provides updated versions of Word Web App, Excel Web App, PowerPoint Web App, and OneNote Web App. Users can view and, in some cases, edit Office documents in SharePoint libraries by using a supported web browser on computers and on many mobile devices. [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219437.aspx#sharepoint)

it support Office files plus PDF.

[how to from technet:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855124.aspx)

Comment: I dont see outlook's msg file being listed from the link you sent. Does this mean the preview on msg file are not supported? Can anyone please verify or test? We dont have SP 2013 and I am trying to build a case for 2013. I would truly appreciated.

Comment: you cant see the outlook message, but if you configure OWA with exchange then you can view the Attachements via OWA.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150495(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PDF, MSG, TIF (and may many other common file types) are not supported according to this article http://www.vizit.com/the-pros-and-cons-of-sharepoint-2013-callout-previews/

Comment: Here is the work around for PDF viewer http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-pdf-previews-with-office-web-apps-2013-march-2013-update